# Can I insert into different databases depending on a query in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two SQLite databases attached into one connection: db1 and db2. I have a view that UNIONS the tables from both databases and adds a column 'database' specifying which database it came from. I am trying to create a trigger on insert into the view that will instead insert into the correct database.

Imagine the following schema for table Data:

```
id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
parent INTEGER,
data   TEXT
```

This would be the schema for the view DataView:

```
id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
database TEXT,
parent   INTEGER,
data     TEXT
```

What I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataViewInsertTrigger AFTER INSERT ON DataView
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO database.Data 
        SELECT database
        FROM DataView
        WHERE id=new.parent 
END;
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, how would I finish the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Borealid is correct that the trigger itself cannot insert into a different file, what you can do is call a custom sqlite function which itself generates a query to insert into a different file.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot insert into an entirely different database based on information you get in a trigger. The trigger executes with a context that is specific to the database which invoked it. The other database would be in a completely unrelated file, in SQLite.

The fact that you have a single connection attaching the two doesn't make one available from the other. What would happen if you tripped the trigger from a query made via a connection which only loaded the one DB?

Perhaps you want two tables in the same database?